# How to setup Gosublime in sublime text 3 in Windows?

Tags: windows, go, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

The main problem here is .. that I have installed the package control and also the gosublime plugin but it is not working.  Also it is not working in the command prompt when I type go. It gives info proving that the go is installed correctly in path I am actually trying to use a separator to set paths for go and java simultaneously which I might be doing wrong.

[ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kslx.png)

Now in sublime text 3 i am receiving an error as

> MarGo: Missing required environment variables: GOPATH
> |                > See the `Quirks` section of USAGE.md for info

I went through  this but it didnt help me

> [Sublime Text: "MarGo: Missing required environment variables: GOPATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516808/sublime-text-margo-missing-required-environment-variables-gopath)

Comment: Related (with alternative solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516808/sublime-text-margo-missing-required-environment-variables-gopath?rq=1

Comment: @atamanroman i dont think you got the point there it is for windows i already mentioned that link above and it is not working out for me and am still getting the error more over the problem is soleved using the shell script which i dont think is viable for windows there must be some command inplace of that for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `GOPATH` environment variable to something like `d:\myprojects\go`. That's where your code and libraries will be stored.

Your code should be located in a folder like `d:\myprojects\go\src\github.com\pandey\coolproject`.

Relevant section from the docs:

> [...]
>
> Test your installation
>
> Check that Go is installed correctly by setting up a workspace and
>   building a simple program, as follows.
>
> Create a directory to contain your workspace, $HOME/work for example,
>   and set the GOPATH environment variable to point to that location.
>
> $ export GOPATH=$HOME/work You should put the above command in your
>   shell startup script ($HOME/.profile for example) or, if you use
>   Windows, follow the instructions above to set the GOPATH environment
>   variable on your system.
>
> Next, make the directories src/github.com/user/hello inside your
>   workspace (if you use GitHub, substitute your user name for user), and
>   inside the hello directory create a file named hello.go with the
>   following contents:
>
> [...]

(https://golang.org/doc/install#testing)

See the Go docs for more details, especially on how to do it on windows: https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: I did setup that workspace now cleanly its compilable and the hello world program is running.when i am using notepad but the error still seems to arise in sublime text and it is still saying mar go missing required variable path GOPATH

Comment: Did you restart sublime after setting GOPATH?

Comment: ok i figured it out and finally removed the margo problem but the only problem now is i cant build the program what i did is i went into gosublime default setting and set the path and gopath in the env then the error was gone but i cant build my code it generates a dialogue box telling to see the documentation and fails to build it .....    i followed        "https://github.com/golang/sublime-build/blob/master/docs/configuration.md" this link

Answer (score 2):

in windows sublime text 3
**ctrl+shift+p** 
type **install package** enter 
search for **golang build**  enter

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a good experience installing gosublime recently, the margo instructions are not very helpful.  You could try gopls instead, it's still in alpha, but it's developed by the go team.  It's a language server for go, that works with a Sublime LSP plugin.

https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls

Instructions for Sublime [are here](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/subl.md).